# How do I get the full filename for an Office document using C# and Office Interop?

Tags: c#, excel, ms-office, office-interop

In the following code, the second line throws an error that reads "Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC".  I suspect I'm getting a null for FullName.  Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
        Foo.DataClasses1DataContext db = new Foo.DataClasses1DataContext();
        string ThisDocument = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ThisWorkbook.FullName;
        byte[] inputBuffer = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(ThisDocument);
        Foo.RFP_Document rfpDocument = new MediaDesk.RFP_Document();
        rfpDocument.DocumentName = "Foobar";
        rfpDocument.DocumentFile = new System.Data.Linq.Binary(inputBuffer);
        db.RFP_Documents.InsertOnSubmit(rfpDocument);
        db.SubmitChanges();
```

For context, this is an Excel 2010 add-in written in C# targeting .NET 4.0.  The objective of the code is to save the document to a database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName`. From MSDN `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ThisWorkBook` returns the workbook where "Macro" is running. Since you don't have a macro this will throw an exception.